# Can someone clarify this code for me

Tags: opengl

I have been going around and looking at different OpenGL 3+ code just to get more familiar. I also follow tutorials and try to code with OpenGL.

so I found a code that draws a sphere. some vertices are found below, and here is the result:

```
.
..
...
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10281: X>0.000747, Y>-0.000275, Z>1.000000! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10282: X>0.000769, Y>-0.000208, Z>1.000000! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10283: X>0.084840, Y>-0.023011, Z>0.996129! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10284: X>0.084840, Y>-0.023011, Z>0.996129! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10285: X>0.000769, Y>-0.000208, Z>1.000000! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10286: X>0.000784, Y>-0.000141, Z>1.000000! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10287: X>0.086522, Y>-0.015533, Z>0.996129! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10288: X>0.086522, Y>-0.015533, Z>0.996129! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10289: X>0.000784, Y>-0.000141, Z>1.000000! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10290: X>0.000793, Y>-0.000072, Z>1.000000! 
Sphere vertices are: >> Vertice 10291: X>0.087546, Y>-0.007936, Z>0.996129!
...
..
.
```

Now the code that I downloaded, draws a sphere in the middle of the screen. It uses glm package. What I don't get is that, how "X=0.087546" or "Z=0.996129" get translated into pixels and drawn onto the screen's axis.

Here is the glm code:

```
//PROJECTION
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
angle = (GLfloat) (i/50 % 360); //to dia gia nan pio argo
//printf("Angle: >>>> %f, \n", angle);  

//VIEW
glm::mat4 View = glm::mat4(1.);
View = glm::translate(View, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, -5.0f)); // x, y, z position ? 
//View = glm::rotate(View, angle * -1.0f, glm::vec3(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
//View = glm::rotate(View, angle * 0.5f, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));

//MODEL
glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0);
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "mvpmatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
```

The window that it is being produced is a 600*600 pixels window. So how X, and Z are mapped to those coordinates?

Comment: "So how X, and Z are mapped to those coordinates?" You're basically asking, "how do vertices get rendered in OpenGL?" While I could write out how this works in an answer, [I've already done that in far greater detail.](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Intro%20Graphics%20and%20Rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

> get translated into pixels and drawn onto the screen's axis.

By going through the transformation pipeline. Vertex coordinates are multiplied with the Modelview matrix, the resulting eye position coordinates are multiplied with the projection matrix, primitives are clipped, then the perspective divide is applied yielding NDC. Those are mapped to the viewport then.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Transformation

Answer (score 0):

The transformations you've shown just map things into the cube bounded by (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1). These are "normalized device coordinates". In normalized device coordinates, X and Y map onto pixels, with (-1,-1) being one corner of the viewport and (1,1) being the opposite corner. Z maps onto values in the depth buffer, with -1 being the near clip plane and 1 being the far clip plane.

glViewport then maps normalized device coordinates, (X,Y) = (-1,-1)..(1,1), to your viewport's actual pixel coordinates, (0,0)..(599,599) in your case.